# Can someone breakdown what's happening in this piece of code?

Tags: string, lisp, common-lisp, do-loops

I'm very new to LISP programming and I'm having a real hard time with the syntax. The following code is from my notes and I know what it does but I'd really appreciate a line by line breakdown to better understand what's happening here. The "`when`" loop seemed pretty simple to understand but specifically I'm having a hard time trying to understand the first 3 lines in the "`do`" loop. Also I'm not sure why `(:= acc (1+ acc)` was used in the last line of the `when` loop.

```
(defun count-lower-case-vowels (str)
  (do ((i 0 (1+ i))
       (acc 0)
       (len (length str)))
      ((= i len) acc)
    (when (or (equal (aref str i) #\a) (equal (aref str i) #\e)
              (equal (aref str i) #\i) (equal (aref str i) #\o)
              (equal (aref str i) #\u))
      (:= acc (1+ acc)))))
```

Comment: What's happening is someone's "TAB" key broke. I recommend using a good code editor that will indent this for you. It will make a lot of things more clear.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo what code editor do you recommend?

Comment: @snk Both Emacs and Vim will indent Lisp code properly.

Answer (score 2):

I'm a big proponent of lots and lots of extra white space, to achieve visual code alignment (in **2D**, yes, as if on a piece of paper) to improve readability:

```
(defun count-lower-case-vowels (str)
  (do (  (i    0      (1+ i) )         ; loop var `i`, its init, step exprs
         (acc  0             )         ; loop var `acc`, its init expr
         (len  (length str)  )  )      ; loop var `len`, its init expr
      ((= i len)                       ; loop stop condition
         acc)                          ; return value when loop stops
    (if                                ; loop body: if
        (find  (aref str i)  "aeiou")  ;              test
      (setf  acc  (1+ acc)))))         ;              consequent
```

Is this better?

It is definitely not the accepted standard of LISP code formatting. But whatever makes it more readable, I think is for the best.

The `i`'s step expression's meaning is that on each step after the loop didn't stop and its body was evaluated, `(setf i (1+ i))` is called. `acc` and `len` have no step expressions, so for them nothing is called on each step.

As to the "`when` loop" you mention, it is not a loop at all, and is not a part at all of the `do` loop's *looping* mechanism. A `when` form is just like an `if` without the alternative, which also allows for multiple statements in the consequent, as if with an implicit `progn`:

```
(when test a1 a2 ...)
===
(if test (progn a1 a2 ...))
```

It just so happens that this loop's *body* consists of one form which is a `when` form. I have re-written it with an equivalent `if`.

Comment: This does make things a bit clearer to understand but could you please explain the significance of (1+ i) in the first line?

Comment: it's a step expression. it means on each step after the loop didn't stop and  its body was evaluated,  `(setf i (1+ i))` is called. `acc` and `len` have no step expressions, so for them nothing is called on each step.

Comment: "_...not the accepted standard of LISP code formatting._" -- All of that whitespace makes my eyes hurt a little bit ;)  It actually seems a bit harder to read for me than conventional formatting. I don't usually do much alignment-specific formatting because then you have to tinker with formatting in regions whenever you make small changes to a bit of code; I mostly just let my editor do its thing. IAC, formatting is personal unless you are working on someone else's code; then it's house rules.

Comment: OP had asked about `:=` in the code from their notes; it might be worth adding something about this not being a Common Lisp function; it's probably an alias for `setf` that the person showing the code was using.

Comment: @adabsurdum indeed that's why I replaced the `:=` with `setf` in my re-write. but I felt I'd have to write a lot of verbiage to explain it, mentioning macros etc, so I left it at that. :) re formatting, your mind is already wired that way. :)

Comment: @snk `1+` is a symbol. In Common Lisp, this symbol names a standard library function which adds `1` to its argument. Unfortunately, its name looks like two thirds of infix syntax.  Newcomers to Lisp will tend to be accustomed to languages in which `1+` and `1 +` mean the same thing.  There is no `2+` function; if you need to add `2`, you must rearrange things to `(+ 2 i)`.

Comment: `:=` is the symbol `"="` in the keyword package. Any symbol token with a leading colon indicates that it's a keyword package symbol: `:bar` is a shorthand for `keyword:bar`: the empty package name to the left of the colon defaults to `keyword`. The code author's `:=` ruse works  because Common Lisp allows keywords to be used as function/macro names. (But not variable names, for the obvious reasons that keywords evaluate to themselves, which variables mustn't do if they are to work as variables).

Answer (score 1):

`do` is a macro expecting 3 parameters:

```
(do ((i 0 (1+ i))
     (acc 0)
     (len (length str))) ;; first argument
    ((= i len) acc) ;; Second one
  (when ...) ;; third
)
```

- The first argument is itself a list, each element of this element being of the following form:

`<var-name> <var-initial-value> <var-next-value>`

In your case, the form `(i 0 (1+ i))` means that in the body of the `do` macro (= in the third argument), you introduce a new, local variable called `i`. It starts with the value `0`, and at each step of the loop, it gets updated to the value `(1+ i)` (*i.e.* it gets incremented by 1).

You see that the second element of this list is `acc 0` with no `<var-next-value>` in it. It means that `acc` won't get updated automatically by the macro, and its value will change only according to what is done in the body.

- The second argument is a list of one or (optionally) two elements `<condition> <return-val>` The first one `<condition>` is stating when to stop the iteration: once it evaluates to true, the macro stops. It gets evaluated before each iteration. The second, optional part, is a form stating what the `do` form returns. By default, it returns `nil`, but if you specify a form there, it will be evaluated before exiting the loop and `return-val` is returned instead.
- The third argument is simply a list of forms that will get executed at each step, provided the `condition` is false.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the code you have posted is older style.

Nowadays it can be written much shorter with `loop` and `find`:

```
(defun count-lower-case-vowels (string)
  (loop for c across string
        count (find c "aeiou")))
```